# Создать папку на рабочем столе со своей иконкой средствами GPO

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, windows-server

Домен на базе Ws2016 и Win10Ent1607.

Не получается subj.

Настройки gpo пользователя. Делаю создание папки на рабочем столе в профиле любого пользователя + c шары (всем доступной) туда пишу 2 файла - ico-нку и desktop.ini.

Папка создается, в ней: desktop.ini (с cсылкой на ico) и сам ico файл.

Права на папку и все что в ней вроде все есть. Но результата нет - папка изображение не меняет.

В desktop.ini пописывал и полный путь к ico и текущий и в старом формате и в новом, не помогает.

типа

[.ShellClassInfo]

IconResource=C:\my.ico,0

после gpupdate /force, f5 на р.столе, входы, выходы из УЗ, не работает.

Т.е. что нужно повторить: на р.столе создаем папку MY, кладем в нее любую иконку, в свойствах папки меняем значок на иконку в папке. Локально работает, через gpo папка, иконка в ней и desktop.ini создаются, а значок у папки не меняется.

[image: prntscr]

Куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Все, раскопал тут https://www.outsidethebox.ms/12151/

Это косяки версии w10.1607. При создании папки атрибут в ней должен быть только 1 при создании через gpo - r\o. После этого все работает.

Извините, что отвлек.